# Which Grails Plugins do not work with Hibernate 4 Plugin?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

The Grails [Hibernate 4 pugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate4) description says:

```
 Hibernate 4 includes some breaking API changes, so not all plugins that 
 work with the Hibernate 3 plugin will work with this one.
```

Which plugins do not work with Hibernate 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much any plugin that depends on Hibernate 3 won't, since there were significant changes between Hibernate 3 and 4, including package changes.

EDIT - I looked through the available plugins and these all seem to require Hibernate 3:

- app-info-hibernate
- db-reverse-engineer
- db-helper-rest
- envers
- hibernate-filter
- hibernate-hijacker
- hibernate-search
- hibernate-spatial
- hibernate-spatial-hdb
- hibernate-spatial-mysql
- hibernate-spatial-oracle
- hibernate-spatial-postgresql
- hibernate-spatial-sqlserver
- hibernate-stats
- infinispan
- lazylob
- memcached
- multi-tenant
- multi-tenant-acegi
- multi-tenant-core
- multi-tenant-ehcache
- multi-tenant-proxy
- multi-tenant-single-db
- multi-tenant-spring-security
- quartz
- searchable

There are probably others, but either they're old or obscure and I didn't bother to check.

Also, the database-migration plugin doesn't explicitly depend on Hibernate 3, but it does use Hibernate 3 if it's available. It soft-loads everything in case you switch to a NoSQL plugin. But it won't work with Hibernate 4 and like all of the others, we'll need either two separate plugins, or developers can choose to stop supporting Hibernate 3 and specify in the docs something like "Use version X for Hibernate 3, or Y or higher for Hibernate 4".

Once we know for sure that a plugin doesn't work with Hibernate 4 I'll add it to an official list on the [plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate4).

Comment: The next question might be "which plugins depends on Hibernate 3?" :-)

Comment: Last update on the [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate4) was done today, hopefully by Burt, people are eager to use new stuffs. :-) @Burt - How about adding this answer to the plugin page too. ;)

Comment: So this means that you cannot use hibernate 4 at the moment, because there are to few plugins that support hibernate 4?

Comment: @confile Any specific functionality you are looking for in version 4 which is not supported or present in version 3?

Comment: No specific functionality. Just for bug fixing.

Comment: I actualy updated hibernate-search to work with hibernate 4, but its only available as a branch in the github: https://github.com/mathpere/grails-hibernate-search-plugin/tree/hibernate4
The hibernate 4 interface is in my opinion better.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith I don't see any notes or dependencies for hibernate 3 in the Quartz 2 plugin. Will a dependency-report help determine?